# How to ignore characters surrounding a URL in regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following regex

```
var URL_REGEX = /(^|[\s\n]|<br\/?>)((?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/)?[\-A-Z0-9\u00A0-\uD7FF\uE000-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFFD+\u0026\u2019@#\/%?=()~_|!:,.;]*[\-A-Z0-9+\u0026@#\/%=~()_|])/gi;
```

I am able to capture the URL in the following correctly:

```
var someString1 = "hello http://stackoverflow.com";
var someString2 = "hello www.stackoverflow.com";
var someString3 = "hello stackoverflow.com";
var someString4 = "hello stackoverflow.com?foo=bar&foo=baz&foo-bar=baz";
```

But suppose I have

```
var wrappedUrl = "hello (www.stackoverflow.com)";
```

I capture the URL along with the parentheses (I don't want that).  How do I only capture the URL?

This fails to get captured.  I get no match:

```
var wrappedUrl = "hello [www.stackoverflow.com]";
```

Comment: You could try removing all opening and closing parentheses, and then just use your current regex.  If you expect nested parentheses, this would fall into the territory of using a parser.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I removed the parenthesis as much as I can (without breaking the capturing groups).  Doesn't work.  Also, see edit... [url] fails to capture.

Comment: I was thinking along the lines of `wrappedUrl.replace("(", "")`.  Is this what you tried, or is there a reason you can't do this?

Comment: Could you add an example of a url that ends with parentheses and should be captured with the parentheses? Because based on the current examples just removing the parentheses from your regex would work.

Comment: Try https://regex101.com/r/bU3bC7/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew How do I ignore the words in front so that match index of the url is 0?

Comment: See [`((https?|ftp)\:\/\/)?([a-z0-9+!*(),;?&=\$_.-]+(\:[a-z0-9+!*(),;?&=\$_.-]+)?@)?([a-z0-9-.]*)\.([a-z]{2,4})(\:[0-9]{2,5})?(\/([a-z0-9+\$_-]\.?)+)*\/?(\?[a-z+&\$_.-][a-z0-9;:@&%=+\/\$_.-]*)?(#[a-z_.-][a-z0-9+\$_.-]*)?`](https://regex101.com/r/bU3bC7/2).

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
/((https?|ftp)\:\/\/)?([a-z0-9+!*(),;?&=\$_.-]+(\:[a-z0-9+!*(),;?&=\$_.-]+)?@)?([a-z0-9-.]*)\.([a-z]{2,4})(\:[0-9]{2,5})?(\/([a-z0-9+\$_-]\.?)+)*\/?(\?[a-z+&\$_.-][a-z0-9;:@&%=+\/\$_.-]*)?(#[a-z_.-][a-z0-9+\$_.-]*)?/gi
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bU3bC7/2)

**Explanation**:

- `((https?|ftp)\:\/\/)?` - Scheme
- `([a-z0-9+!*(),;?&=\$_.-]+(\:[a-z0-9+!*(),;?&=\$_.-]+)?@)?` - Username and password
- `([a-z0-9-.]*)\.([a-z]{2,3})` - Host name or IP address
- `(\:[0-9]{2,5})?` - Port address
- `(\/([a-z0-9+\$_-]\.?)+)*\/?` - Path
- `(\?[a-z+&\$_.-][a-z0-9;:@&%=+\/\$_.-]*)?` - GET query
- `(#[a-z_.-][a-z0-9+\$_.-]*)?` - anchor

See the JS demo:

```js
var re = /((https?|ftp)\:\/\/)?([a-z0-9+!*(),;?&=\$_.-]+(\:[a-z0-9+!*(),;?&=\$_.-]+)?@)?([a-z0-9-.]*)\.([a-z]{2,4})(\:[0-9]{2,5})?(\/([a-z0-9+\$_-]\.?)+)*\/?(\?[a-z+&\$_.-][a-z0-9;:@&%=+\/\$_.-]*)?(#[a-z_.-][a-z0-9+\$_.-]*)?/gi; 
var str = `hello http://stackoverflow.com
hello www.stackoverflow.com
hello stackoverflow.com
hello stackoverflow.com?foo=bar&foo=baz&foo-bar=baz
hello [www.stackoverflow.com]
hello (www.stackoverflow.com)`;
 
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    document.body.innerHTML += m[0] + "<br/>";
}
```

Comment: How is this used in `string.replace()` where you still retain all leading and trailing string?  Example: `"hello [url_match]"` --> `"hello [<a href='{{match}}'>{{match}}</a>]"`

Comment: `str.replace(/regex/gi, "<a href='$&'>$&</a>")`. The `$&` is a backreference to the whole match value.

Comment: Excellent.  Works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this regular expression `/((http|https|ftp):?\/\/)?[a-z-A-Z]*(\.[a-z-A-Z]*)+(\?([a-z-A-Z0-9_]+=[a-z-A-Z0-9_]+(&)?)*)?/`
And it works perfectly in all cases you have showed.
Anyway it will be good to have look into RegExp references, and try build expression from blank on your own.